# A value of type 'File' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I want to ask a question about my code.
First, the function I want is for the user to load and stack photos, decorate the blank screen, and finally save the entire screen as a single photo.
So, I made a blank screen in a widget "ipage".
And by using the imagepicker package, And I made the user pick the photo in “image” in a class "pickimage".
But when I try to run the code, "A value of type 'File' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget?'."  <- at the setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
How can I fix it?

I am a non-major who lacks coding knowledge.
Please forgive me for the lack of questions.
Thanks in advance to everyone who replies.
My code is in the below.
(The code for the row icons below has been omitted.)

```
class Makeipage2_2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Makeipage2_2> createState() => _Makeipage2_2State();
}


class _Makeipage2_2State extends State<Makeipage2_2> {
  Widget? image;
  double? _x;
  double? _y;

  Widget ipage() {
   return Stack(
   children: [
      Container(
        height: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.8),
        ),
        child: Positioned(
          left: _x,
          top: _y,
          child: Draggable(
            child: image!,
            feedback: image!,
            childWhenDragging: const SizedBox(),
            onDragEnd: (dragdetails) {
              setState(() {
                  _x = dragdetails.offset.dx;
                  _y = dragdetails.offset.dy;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}


  Future pickImage() async {
   try {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image == null) return;

    final imageTemp = File(image.path); 
    setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
   } catch (e) {
     print('Failed to pick image: $e');
   }
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             ipage(),
             const SizedBox(
               height: 10,
             ),
             Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
               FadingImageButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   pickImage();
                 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have a `File` of an image, to display it, you need an `Image` widget.

There is a constructor just for that:

```
this.image = Image.file(imageTemp)
```

This will create an `Image` widget from the file you got from the picker.

Comment: Thank you! The error is disappeared. There are no errors before debuging.
But when I ran the code on the emulator, It said "Null check operator used on a null value ." I coudln't find where the problem is.

Comment: Well, this line `child: image!,` will throw that error, if `image` is still null. I guess it's null before you pick the first, so you need a way to deal with it other than just making your compiler shut up about it by slapping a `!` on it.

Comment: okay i will find new way, thank you!